# An unknown pattern in $π^k$.

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, pattern-recognition

While trying to find a pattern in $π$, by taking the idea from [$n$ such that the digits immediately after the decimal point of $\pi^n$ give $n$ again](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2888642/n-such-that-the-digits-immediately-after-the-decimal-point-of-pin-give-n)

By using wolfram alpha calculator first I am writing the examples of my invesgation

π<sup>3</sup> = 31.00627668....

π<sup>5</sup> = 306.0196847....

π<sup>9</sup> = 29809.09933344....

π<sup>10</sup> = 93648.0474760830....

π<sup>11</sup> = 294204.01797389059....

π<sup>18</sup> = 888582403.07126338067....

As we can see that in each example after a decimal place there is '0'. But I don't know any math programming language to calculate further more values.

Now the question is that is there are infinite values 'k' such that:

π<sup>k</sup> = .....abcdefhg.0wpywqx....      (in which after decimal place '0' will be there)

Any hint or solution is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Consider using Python.

Comment: @BillWallis sir will you please calculate more values, as i am weak n=in programming

Comment: There probably are infinitely many such $k$, but it's probably quite difficult to prove conclusively.

Comment: @Arthur ya I also think same but don't know from where to start to prove it.

Comment: The ones less than $200$: $\{3, 5, 9, 10, 11, 18, 20, 36, 54, 59,$ $73, 81, 88, 90, 93, 106, 108, 140, 151, 182\}$

Comment: @Winther Unsurprisingly, your list has about $200/10=20$ items on it. I would expect every digit to occur roughly equally often.

Comment: @Winther thanks for your time to calculate these values.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis may be on moving higher some pattern will be there

Comment: If you want to compute some more and have mathematica, here is a simple code (for any number): `num = \[Pi]; digits = 500; Block[{$MinPrecision = digits}, l = {}; kmax = Floor[digits/Log10[num]; Do[If[N[FractionalPart[num^k], digits] < 0.1, AppendTo[l, k]];, {k, 1, kmax}]; Print[l]];`

Comment: @Winther still i don't have mathematica but i will soon buy it. thanks for your code.

Comment: “Almost every” non-integer greater than 1 will have powers whose first digit after the decimal is 0 on average one tenth of the time. Yet it is an open problem to find a particular example for which this is true. So no one knows how to answer your question about $\pi$. See section two of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.5996.pdf.

Comment: @MikeEarnest thanks for sharing that link.

Comment: @Winther if k=6561 also satisfy the condition.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi%5E6561+-+Floor%5Bpi%5E6561%5D

Answer (score 2):

Here's a histogram of the first digit (to the right of ".") values for $\pi^n$ for $1 \leq n \leq 500$:  Clearly the results are random and there is nothing special about the value $0$ in that digit position:

[image: histogram]

Here's the *Mathematica* code for generating the histogram:

```
piList = Table[N[π^n, 500], {n, 500}];
digitList = IntegerPart /@ (10 (FractionalPart /@ piList));
Histogram[digitList]
```

Comment: sir is there no way to mathematically prove it?